# Larave 9 probleme : Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: laravel-9

Good morning

when I send the product it shows me this message:

Trying to access array offset on value of type null

here is my code

```html
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ $product['id'] }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ $product['product_name'] }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ $product['product_code'] }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ $product['product_color'] }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ $product['category']['category_name'] }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ $product['section']['name'] }}
    </td>
    <td> 
        @if($product['admin_type']=="vendor") 
        <a target="_blank" href="{{ url('admin/view-vendor-details/'.$product['admin_id']) }}">{{ ucfirst($product['admin_type']) }}</a> 
        @else 
        {{ ucfirst($product['admin_type']) }} 
        @endif 
    </td>
    <td> 
        @if($product['status']==1) 
        <a class="updateProductStatus" id="product-{{ $product['id'] }}" product_id="{{ $product['id'] }}" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i style="font-size: 25px;" class="mdi mdi-bookmark-check" status="Active"></i>
        </a> 
        @else 
        <a class="updateProductStatus" id="product-{{ $product['id'] }}" product_id="{{ $product['id'] }}" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i style="font-size: 25px;" class="mdi mdi-bookmark-outline" status="Inactive"></i>
        </a> 
        @endif
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ url('admin/add-edit-product/'.$product['id']) }}">
            <i style="font-size: 25px;" class="mdi mdi-pencil-box"></i>
        </a> 
        <?php /*
        <a title="Product" class="confirmDelete" href="{{ url('admin/delete-product/'.$product['id']) }}">
            <i style="font-size: 25px;" class="mdi mdi-file-excel-box"></i>
        </a> */ 
        ?> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="confirmDelete" module="product" moduleid="{{ $product['id'] }}">
            <i style="font-size: 25px;" class="mdi mdi-file-excel-box"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's likely that either $product['category'] or $product['section'] is null for some of the products in the loop.

```php
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $product['id'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product['product_name'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product['product_code'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product['product_color'] }}</td>
    <td>
        @if(isset($product['category']['category_name']))
            {{ $product['category']['category_name'] }}
        @endif
    </td>
    <td>
        @if(isset($product['section']['name']))
            {{ $product['section']['name'] }}
        @endif
    </td>
    <td> 
        @if($product['admin_type']=="vendor") 
            <a target="_blank" href="{{ url('admin/view-vendor-details/'.$product['admin_id']) }}">{{ ucfirst($product['admin_type']) }}</a> 
        @else 
            {{ ucfirst($product['admin_type']) }} 
        @endif 
    </td>
    <td> 
        @if($product['status']==1) 
            <a class="updateProductStatus" id="product-{{ $product['id'] }}" product_id="{{ $product['id'] }}" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i style="font-size: 25px;" class="mdi mdi-bookmark-check" status="Active"></i>
            </a> 
        @else 
            <a class="updateProductStatus" id="product-{{ $product['id'] }}" product_id="{{ $product['id'] }}" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i style="font-size: 25px;" class="mdi mdi-bookmark-outline" status="Inactive"></i>
            </a> 
        @endif
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ url('admin/add-edit-product/'.$product['id']) }}">
            <i style="font-size: 25px;" class="mdi mdi-pencil-box"></i>
        </a> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="confirmDelete" module="product" moduleid="{{ $product['id'] }}">
            <i style="font-size: 25px;" class="mdi mdi-file-excel-box"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use nullsafe(?) operator

```php
 {{ $product?->category?->category_name }}
```

the more clarify
Call the foo property if it does exist in the $null variable

```php
$null = null;

echo $null?->foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [data_get](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-data-get) to avoid error if the key you are accessing doesn't exist

so instead of

```
{{ $product['id'] }}` and `{{ $product['category']['category_name'] }}
```

you can do

```
{{ data_get($product, 'id') }}` and `{{ data_get($product, 'category.category_name') }}
```

even for if

```
@if($product['status']==1)
```

change it to

```
@if( data_get($product, 'status') == 1 )
```